# How to track store or studio name/id in Google data studio?

Tags: regex, google-analytics, reporting, looker-studio, enhanced-ecommerce

I have a website, which has multiple stores/studios. Whenever a user placed the order, thank you page look like this-

abc.com/auckland/checkout/order-received/88410/
&
abc.com/hamilton/checkout/order-received/88411/

Here Auckland & Hamilton are store/studio names. How can I create a filter in Google Data Studio on the basis of store/studio name?

Comment: **Needs details [REVISION 1]**: Could you provide a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report [TO-DO] and sample data set(s) / Google Sheet [TO-DO] of the scenario, that shows 1) Input table(s) (~9 rows) in the Question [TO-DO] and a table / chart in the Report [TO-DO] 2) Expected output in the Question [TO-DO] & Report [TO-DO] 3) An attempt at solving the issue in Question [TO-DO] & Report [TO-DO]? Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to visualise and pinpoint a suggestion to a specific use case

Answer (score 0):

To extract the 1st part of the url, following code can be used. There will be two new fields and for each a filter can be build.

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(url_field,r"/([^/]*)/")
```

and

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(url_field,r"&[^/]+/([^/]*)/")
```